# Is it possible to change the log level of an AWS Lambda at runtime?

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, log4j, slf4j, log-level

I'm running a lamba on AWS, and using slf4j for logging

Part of the project requirements is that the log level can be set at runtime, using an environment variable, but I'm not sure if that's possible

I'm using the following code, but changing the environment variable "LOG_LEVEL" in the UI to "DEBUG" has no effect to what is added to the CloudWatch logs. Is this possible?

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<Integer, String> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLambdaHandler.class);

    static {
        org.apache.log4j.Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
        String logLevel = (System.getenv("LOG_LEVEL") != null) ? System.getenv("LOG_LEVEL") : "INFO";
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.toLevel(logLevel));
    }

    public String myHandler(int myCount, Context context) {

        LOGGER.debug("Entering myHandler lambda handler";
        LOGGER.info("Handling myCount {}", myCount);
        int returnValue = myCount * 2;
        LOGGER.debug("MyHandler return value {}", returnValue);
        return returnValue;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using the amazon version of log4j2, and making a change to the log4j2.xml configuration file
Add these dependencies to maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

use the environment variable in the level of the logger in the configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration
    packages="com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2">
    <Appenders>
        <Lambda name="Lambda">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Lambda>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${env:LOG_LEVEL}">
            <AppenderRef ref="Lambda" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

finally, use the log4j2 logger in the lambda itself

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<Void, Void> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyLambdaHandler .class);

    public Void handleRequest(Void myVoid, Context context) {

        LOGGER.error("Log info enabled: {}", LOGGER.isInfoEnabled());
        LOGGER.info("Info messge");
        LOGGER.error("Log error enabled: {}",  LOGGER.isErrorEnabled());
        LOGGER.error("Error Message");
        LOGGER.error("Log trace enabled: {}",  LOGGER.isTraceEnabled());
        LOGGER.trace("trace message");
        LOGGER.error("Log warning enabled: {}",  LOGGER.isWarnEnabled());
        LOGGER.warn("warn message");
        LOGGER.error("Log debug enabled: {}",  LOGGER.isDebugEnabled());
        LOGGER.debug("debug message");
        return null;

    }

}
```

then set the LOG_LEVEL environment variable to the appropriate level to see the the relevant entries in the logs

Comment: Were you using the maven shade plugin with this Lambda and got it working with that too?

Comment: I've added the code to a github repo here: https://github.com/tetsujin1979/aws-log-level

Comment: @JosephMcCarthy I created a lambda from your git repo and set the env variable LOG_LEVEL to info but I still dont see any log message in log output, I just see the below(skipping start request and report request msg)
%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%nEND RequestId: 4ecf66b5-480e-4068-a9c1-e32433e487d9
Am I missing anything ?

Comment: The cloudwatch logs also says "ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]" and other similar messages

Comment: Ok, I was able to resolve the issue by using the shade plugin config defined here : https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-log4j2

Comment: @JosephMcCarthy did you verify if the logs are appropriately logged, i.e for me even when LOG_LEVEL=INFO everything is being logged.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible! You need to take care of two things:

- One, update your lambda environment variable
- Two, ensure that log4j will pick up the update

For the first problem, all you need to do is pass a lambda environment variable with name `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and value `"-DLOG_LEVEL=DEBUG"`.

For the second point, you can add this to your Java project `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` with content something like

```
log4j.rootCategory=${LOG_LEVEL}, LAMBDA
LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN=%5p
LOG_PATTERN=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] boot%X{context} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} [%t] - %c{1}: %m%n
log4j.appender.LAMBDA=com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j.LambdaAppender
log4j.appender.LAMBDA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LAMBDA.layout.conversionPattern=${LOG_PATTERN}
```

And that's it!

If everything goes well you should soon see in your logs a line reading something like

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -DLOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

and hopefully start seeing some debug statements.

Notice how `LOG_LEVEL` is embedded in the value of the lambda variable as opposed to being the variable name. This is a useful indirect way to feed JVM arguments down a lambda which you can then use as system properties.
Kudos to https://zenidas.wordpress.com/recipes/system-properties-for-a-java-lambda-function/